# Web page malfunctions on developer console call

Tags: javascript

[My webpage](https://mikewarren.me/YALApp/test.html) sometimes exhibits weird, possibly undefined, behavior when I bring up the Developer Console in Google Chrome. What are all possible causes?

Here's one unexpected behavior: (in this case, the styling, that was up, went away when Developer Console came up) [image]

Comment: Is there any beak-point in your script files. browser stop page loading when it pause at break-point. or you can check in network that is your resource file loaded or not.

Comment: You're not being very clear, what styling, and what is "up"? When the console opens, it resizes the window, which can trigger styling changes.

Comment: I am using jQuery UI. I just cleared all the breakpoints and the unexpected behavior just went away. I'm going to keep testing to get statistically significant results, tho

Comment: Is this happening in incognito mode too?

Comment: I haven't even thought to test that...

Comment: I just tested it. I reproduced the error, and with no breakpoints on.

Comment: I closed the console, and the page went back to normal, as if it finished loading.